# How to parse 16bit hex from char iterator

Tags: rust

Say I have a `str` `s` with the value `foo004Frtz` and I want to use an iterator to parse the string.
Goal is to in the end parse the `004F` into a `u16`.

```
let it = s.chars().into_iter();
```

Assuming that `it` is at the correct position (second `o`), how do I parse the `u16` from the iterator?

I tried:

```
let x = u16::from_str_radix(hex, 16); // Should be set to 79
```

but have a hard time constructing `hex` from the iterator.

**EDIT:**
Make value a bit more complicated.

Comment: You can use [`as_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.as_str).

Answer (score 0):

Thx to @Chayim I figured out one solution:

```rust
let hex = &it.as_str()[..4];
let x = u16::from_str_radix(&hex, 16).unwrap();
```

Not sure though how efficient `as_str()` is...

Comment: `it.as_str()` is free, it does not copy the original string, it just returns the remaining string slice (which is part of the original you passed in sliced at the position the iterator is currently on)